# Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common

Tags: tfs

I am trying to find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common. I can't find it in Nuget or in the files for Visual Studio. We currently use version 2018 of TFS.

Before anyone tells me to download the Nuget package for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, I get the following message when I try to do so:

**The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated, has security vulnerabilities or shouldn't be used anymore.**

I can find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll in the TFS Server files, but that does not help me with Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common. I still get messages such as:

**BC30456   'CatalogQueryOptions' is not a member of 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common'.**

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common` is now deprecated by Microsoft. You can still download older packages, but it only can only be used in **Team Foundation Server 2015**.

Click [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.102.0) for the old version of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` package.  And then, you can use the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common` namespace which is included in it.